# Is Bitcoin Hong Kong Exchange a legitimate trading platform?

Tags: exchanges, trading, fraud

I've think the Site of [BTCHKEX](http://www.btchkex.com) appears fraudulent to me. Has anyone dealt with them?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you asked any of the asian community? I am asking around myself at this time.  If you are looking for an asian exchange, there are some that do CNY to btc that are trustworthy.

Answer (score 1):

They did not appear fraudulent, only overpriced.
But I only made a handful of transactions.
Anyway they are closed now, my wallet is still there.